# How can Slaves automatically detect new Cores on Solr Master?

Tags: solr, replication, solr4

I have a Solr environment with one master and some slaves. The index consists of multiple Solr Cores that share their Schema but need to be separated from each other.

From time to time, there are new Cores added to the Master via Software. At the moment, for replication I have to add these new Cores to the Slaves manually, which sucks.

Is there a way to have the Slaves automatically detect new Cores on the Master, create them locally and start replication right away? Your help is very much appreciated.

Update: The current setup ist Solr3, but a migration towards Solr4 is already planned. So this is basically a Solr4 question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of any automatic core detection/setup for Slaves in the standard replication settings. You might be able to automate this yourself using the [CoreAdmin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) commands via software. Or since you are migrating towards Solr 4, you should look into using [SolrCloud](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/SolrCloud) as this may provide some of the functionality you are seeking.

Comment: In the end, this turned out to be the correct suggestion.